# How to reduce stored procedure execution time?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have stored procedure (sql server 2008) that look like this:

```
select...
union
select...
union
select...
union
select...
union
select...
union
select...
union
select...
```

All in all i have 8 "select" in there.
Usually execution time is o.k. but sometimes it takes along time.
I found out that after drop&create the problem is gone.
why is it happening? and what can i do to solve this?
Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean for `drop&create`? Do you mean drop then create procedure again? What is exec time when you run that query in your SSMS?

Comment: It's impossible to answer without knowing what the query does. The *only* thing visible here is `UNION` with its implicit `DISTINCT`. Is the query well written or does it force the server to scan tables multiple times? Are the tables indexed? Does the query *prevent* the server from using indexes perhaps?

Comment: Dropping and creating the stored procedure again is no different here than recompiling the stored procedure. This suggests that the queries are poorly written and result in bad execution plans. Are you using [catch-all parameters](https://sqlinthewild.co.za/index.php/2009/03/19/catch-all-queries/) for example?The quick & dirty fix would be to add `WITH RECOMPILE`. A better solution is probably to get read of those parameters altogether and use an ORM to generate queries with dynamic conditions

Comment: It does sound like a parameter sniffing issue created by a 'one query to solve all' type problem.

Comment: Generally `union all` is faster then `union`, no sort required. Is it an option here?

Comment: I highly recommend to read [Slow in the Application, Fast in SSMS?](http://www.sommarskog.se/query-plan-mysteries.html) by Erland Sommarskog.

Answer (score 1):

This is too long for a comment.

The most likely reason the query is slow is because the optimizer -- despite doing the best that it can -- produces a suboptimal execution plan.

The most likely reason the query speeds up after recreating the tables is that the statistics gathered on the tables are more accurate, allowing the optimizer to choose a better execution plan.

What can you do about this?  Look at the execution plan that works and add query hints so the query always uses the same algorithms.  In my experience, this usually involves fixing the join algorithms.

Note:  There are other possibilities as well.  For instance, table and index fragmentation can cause significant performance penalties under some circumstances and recreating tables can fix those problems.